# Monitor network request URL and response content (Throw custom exceptions)

Tags: ajax, debugging, xmlhttprequest, response, monitoring

How can network requests be monitored and evaluated for their request URL, parameters, request, and response data?

#### Desired solution

I want to be notified or being given a custom exception, if specific content occurs in request or response.

#### Example

Assume a web application with many dynamic Ajax requests. A request or response might contain a broken value, e.g. `undefined`.

Request URL:

```
http://localhost:8080/app/?undefined=1
```

Response JSON data:

```json
{"undefined":"1"}
```

---

### Attempts

- Filtering for request content in Dev Tools is not possible
- PostMan tests seem not viable (e.g. no user interactions)

---

### Not tried/found yet

Guesses of what might work ...

- Software to intercepts requests and log/alert details
- Proxying any URLs on an OS via some standalone application

Comment: I am not sure I understand why you can't do that with Postman tests. You can write any JS code and throw errors/fail the test if the content matches your predefined condition.

Comment: Usually yes, but in my particular case, the requests are created dynamically, with varying URLs, based on user interactions, and only _sometimes_ have unwanted values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If importing `axios`, you could leverage custom interceptors:

```
// Add a response interceptor
axios.interceptors.response.use(function (response) {
    // Any status code that lie within the range of 2xx cause this function to trigger
    // Do something with response data
    return response;
  }, function (error) {
    // Any status codes that falls outside the range of 2xx cause this function to trigger
    // Do something with response error
    return Promise.reject(error);
  });


// Similar functionality can be achieved for request
axios.interceptors.request.use(function (config) {
    // Do something before request is sent
    return config;
  }, function (error) {
    // Do something with request error
    return Promise.reject(error);
  });
```

Comment: Further guidance from docs: https://axios-http.com/docs/interceptors

Answer (score 0):

#### Proxy software

For this case, any proxy that comes with logging ability, or can be extended:

- https://mitmproxy.org
- https://github.com/http-party/node-http-proxy

  - *Exemplary for many variants under NodeJS*

#### Tunneling

Expose `localhost` to a domain for testing:

- https://ngrok.com

Use the logging capability to get request details:

- https://ngrok.com/docs/ngrok-agent/api#list-requests

---

#### Localhost vs. 127.0.0.1

`localhost` should better become `127.0.0.1` or a custom dev domain. On MacOS, `localhost` did not work with HTTP interceptor browser plugins.